# My site will not process Credit Cards

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Authorized.net was processing my credit card purchases until the end of Feb. As of 3/1/2011 they no longer will process electronic cigarette transactions. Processing network told us we would have a seamless transition over to a processor called EPN. Now we can not process and credit card orders at all. I have been told it's an SSL concern (EPN says no) I have been told it's an issue between Authorized.net and EPN again I am told no. Might site worked and functioned fine until the "seamless" transition took place. Please help me out here.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Is there a coding question here?

Comment: You might need to post more specific details about your problem to get help here. Are you getting an error message on your transactions? Do you have a sandbox environment to test your integration?

Comment: @user654389 Unless its a programming question - it does not belong here.

Comment: And without any more details, it's hard to recommend where to move it to.

Comment: There needs to be an actual question for us to answer. As of right now all we can do is speculate. Please give us more information about what you've done to troubleshoot this and ask a specific question about what you need help with.

Comment: FWIW, you're problem is not with Authorize.Net. If they won't accept your business type then they're not in the picture at all. So your issue is between EPN and your website. Have you integrated their API? If non then there's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess a few questions that might point you in the right direction:

1. What part was supposed to be 'seamless'? The processors's end switching from Authorize.net to EPN or your integration?
2. How were you using Authorize.net? The simple way where they collected all the info on their pages, or did you do the API integration where you posted information
3. If the latter option, does EPN have the exact same API as Autherize.net? If not, you will need to make coding changes

Comment: Don't see how you can answer when there is no question yet.

Comment: @David actually, I think he did a pretty decent job given how little there was to go on. I agree that there's not enough info, but these are questions that will help the OP (and he did say "Please help me out here." which isn't technically a question, but is kind of close.)

Comment: There may not be a specified question, but there is a problem. My hope was to get him running in the right direction so as to get the correct question to ask.

Comment: Would expect a professional programmer to know what an API was.  Still don't know what the question is ...  Oh well.  Well done for trying. :-)